# Why it exits even though teradown is False?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying that if i put `teardown=True` it exits chrome after executing the code, and when i put it false i doesn't exit chrome

Here is run.py:

```
from booking.booking import Booking

with Booking() as bot:
    bot.land_first_page()
    print("Exiting...")
```

**init**.py:

```
print('I will print first')
```

constants.py:

```
BASE_URL = "https://www.booking.com"
```

booking:

```
import booking.constants as const
import os
from selenium import webdriver

class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"/Users/3bod/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64", teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()
        else:
            print('gg')

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)
```

```
Compiler:
I will print first
Exiting...
gg

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.